# How can i include label-info from twitter boostrap in my own class definition?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, less

With twitter-bootstrap, I'm trying to define my own css label class, but I got an error.

.label-info is defined in [this file](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/less/labels-badges.less)  that way:

```
// Colors
// Only give background-color difference to links (and to simplify, we don't qualifty with `a` but [href] attribute)
.label,
.badge {
  // Important (red)
  &-important         { background-color: @errorText; }
  &-important[href]   { background-color: darken(@errorText, 10%); }
  // Warnings (orange)
  &-warning           { background-color: @orange; }
  &-warning[href]     { background-color: darken(@orange, 10%); }
  // Success (green)
  &-success           { background-color: @successText; }
  &-success[href]     { background-color: darken(@successText, 10%); }
  // Info (turquoise)
  &-info              { background-color: @infoText; }
  &-info[href]        { background-color: darken(@infoText, 10%); }
  // Inverse (black)
  &-inverse           { background-color: @grayDark; }
  &-inverse[href]     { background-color: darken(@grayDark, 10%); }
}
```

**What i'd like is in** 
my_label.css.less:

```
@import "twitter/bootstrap";

.my_label{
    .label;
    .label-info;
}
```

The `.label works`

But `.label-info` gives me an error: `.label-info is undefined`

So how can I include `.label-info` in my class?

I'm working with rails and less-rails-boostrap gem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't much advantage to what you are trying to do, specifically with modifier classes for labels, since there is so little code involved.  As you can see from your example, the code for `.label-info` is basically

```
.label {
  &-info              { background-color: @infoText; };
}
```

If you really want to combine the .label class with your new class, as in your example, you are better off grouping it with the `.label` class to reduce code, like so:

```
.label,
.label-notice {
  // declarations
}
```

Although keep in mind this is kind of negating one of the distinct advantages and best practices of bootstrap.

As for the custom class, my suggestion would be to add a new semantic class using the same pattern as the other modifiers, and use the background color defined for `.label-info`, like this:

```
.label,
.badge {
  // Info (turquoise)
  &-info              { background-color: @infoText; }
  &-info[href]        { background-color: darken(@infoText, 10%); }
  ...

  // Notice (your custom class)
  &-notice            { background-color: @infoText; // extend with your properties here }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to ask the same question too.

And I have an idea to solve this:
**change bootstrap.css to bootstrap.less** and import it, then you can use
both .label and .label-info and all the other classes.

I hope `less` can support this "feature" in the future.

I searched 'mixin' in `less-1.3.3.js` and found this:

```
            //
            // A Mixin call, with an optional argument list
            //
            //     #mixins > .square(#fff);
            //     .rounded(4px, black);
            //     .button;
            //
            // The `while` loop is there because mixins can be
            // namespaced, but we only support the child and descendant
            // selector for now.
            //
```

So, I think mixins with namespace will be support in the future.